# Qt directory tree from data

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I would like to create a file-directory tree from data in a variable (not physical on drive).
I have got data like this:
`data = ['folder1/file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'folder2/'file4']`
And I would like to show it like a directory tree.

- folder1

  - file1
- folder2

  - file4
- file2
- file3

I've just found anwsers how to do it for existing folders.
It does not have to be Python code, I think I will be able to read what I need from any other language.
Which class should I use and how to pass data to it?

Regards,
Marek

Comment: Something like [this](https://jpnaude.github.io/Qtilities/page_observer_widgets.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

data = ['folder1/file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'folder2/file4']

treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)
treeWidget.setMinimumSize(600, 400)

items = []

for item in data:
    itemparts = item.split('/')

    entry = QTreeWidgetItem(None, [itemparts[0]])
    partentitem = entry

    if len(itemparts) > 1:
        for i in itemparts[1:]:
            childitem = QTreeWidgetItem(None, [i])
            partentitem.addChild(childitem)
            partentitem = childitem

    items.append(entry)

treeWidget.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)

treeWidget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks, useful, but I already used QStandardItemModel and QStandardItem. Works almost the same as yours. :)

Comment: @jotto. In that case, why did you ask the question? And, more to the point, what exactly *is* your question?

Comment: Because I made it up after I asked a question :)

Comment: finally I used your method and modified it. You can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868738/duplicates-in-qtreewidget) @L-rac