# Duplicates in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have made a tree widgety with data from a list using help from this post.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33825934/4151075. 
But I have a problem that it adds me duplicates to my view.

```
Dir1
    Dir2
        A.txt
    Dir2
        B.txt
```

I have managed to fix this for top level folders, but I have a problem with inner ones.
I have difficulties with accessing childs od childs in items variable.
Isn't there any parser included in Qt for viewing list of paths?
Best regards

Comment: Are you looking for an implemented parser which will take all the pathes and check whether they exist or not? If yes, then you have to write it by yourself. As far as I know there is no such "battery" in Qt.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to create a tree of fake (not existing) directories. For example to show file names for files which will be packed into *.zip file.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Not sure this is what the OP wanted. I guess the question was just about retrieving a list of paths contained in a QTreeWidget??

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think so! Just have a look at the code in the previous question provided by author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem and created a method that takes a list of paths as an argument and return a list of QWidgetItems.

```
def tree_widget_list(self, show_list):
    """
    Creates a list for updating tree widget
    :param show_list:
    :return:
    """
    items = []
    for item in show_list:
        item_parts = item.split('\\')

        entry = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(None, [item_parts[0]])
        items_text = [i.text(0) for i in items]
        if entry.text(0) not in items_text:
            parent_item = entry
        else:
            parent_index = items_text.index(entry.text(0))
            parent_item = items[parent_index]

        if len(item_parts) > 1:
            for i in item_parts[1:]:
                child_item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(None, [i])
                child_list_text = [parent_item.child(i).text(0) for i in xrange(parent_item.childCount())]
                if child_item.text(0) in child_list_text:
                    child_index = child_list_text.index(child_item.text(0))
                    parent_item = parent_item.child(child_index)
                else:
                    parent_item.addChild(child_item)
                    parent_item = child_item
        items.append(entry) if entry.text(0) not in items_text else None
    return items
```

Then just use:

```
show_list = ["ABC\\AAA.txt", "DEF\\abc.txt", "ABC\\readme.txt"]
items = self.tree_widget_list(show_list)
self.cfg_src_tree.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)
```

For example for list `['MODULE\\designer\\qaxwidget.dll', 'MODULE\\designer\\qquickwidget.dll', 'MODULE\\designer\\qwebview.dll', 'MODULE\\iconengines\\qsvgicon.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qdds.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qgif.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qicns.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qico.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qjp2.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qjpeg.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qmng.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qsvg.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qtga.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qtiff.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qwbmp.dll', 'MODULE\\imageformats\\qwebp.dll', 'MODULE\\platforms\\qminimal.dll', 'MODULE\\platforms\\qoffscreen.dll', 'MODULE\\platforms\\qwindows.dll', 'MODULE\\printsupport\\windowsprintersupport.dll', 'MODULE\\sqldrivers\\qsqlite.dll', 'MODULE\\sqldrivers\\qsqlmysql.dll', 'MODULE\\sqldrivers\\qsqlodbc.dll', 'MODULE\\sqldrivers\\qsqlpsql.dll']`
We have got:

[image]